# To write a test method to issue a SOQL query to get related data for records in the Trigger.new and Trigger.old lists

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

my trigger code is:

```
trigger candidateTrigger on Candidate__c (before delete) {
        for (Job_Application__c jobApp : [SELECT Candidate__c
                                          FROM Job_Application__c
                                          WHERE Candidate__c
                                          IN :Trigger.oldMap.keySet()]) {
            Trigger.oldMap.get(jobApp.Candidate__c).addError(
                       'Cannot delete candidate with a job application');
        }
    }
```

and my test code is:

```
  @isTest private class TestCandidate 
    { 
        static testMethod void testPriceChange() 
           { 
             Job_Application__c jobApp = new Job_Application__c(Candidate__c = 'New Candidate'); 
             insert jobApp;
             Candidate__c[] cand = new Candidate__c[]{ new Candidate__c(Name = 'Candidate 1'), new Candidate__c(Name = 'Candidate 2') };

             insert cand; 
           } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your test code, the candidate is not actually related to the job application, so the trigger conditions wouldn't be met anyway, and you never actually delete the candidate to test the trigger.  Relate a canidate to the job application and then delete the canidate.

Try this

```
  @isTest private class TestCandidate { 
                static testMethod void testPriceChange() {
                     Candidate__c cand1 = new Candidate__c(Name = 'Candidate 1');    
                     insert cand1; 

                     //Should Work, as no application is related
                     delete cand;


                     Candidate__c cand2 = new Candidate__c(Name = 'Candidate 1');    
                     insert cand2; 

                     Job_Application__c jobApp = new Job_Application__c(Candidate__c = cand2.Id);
                     insert jobApp;


                     try{
                         // This should throw an exception, since there is a job application related to this candidate
                         delete cand2;                    
                         System.assert(false);
                     }
                     catch (DMLException e){

                     }


                }
        }
```

Comment: You should also add some assertions in there as well, but this will at least give you the code coverage.

Comment: can you please explain me about what assertions to be included

Comment: I tried the code but the test is failed and the cause was given as System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0A9000000GZBR5EAP; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Cannot delete candidate with a job application: []

Comment: Just updated the code to test the both conditions.

Comment: i tried this but there was an error and the error is  Error: Compile Error: Expression of type System.DmlException has no member named getMessage

Comment: I gave a master-detail relation ship to job application and candidate with job application related to candidate.

Comment: Now i have to write the code to test the trigger so that the trigger gets code coverage

Comment: Sorry, typo.  Should be 'e.getMessage()'.  Updated the code above

Comment: Again an error message saying that Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: System.assert(String, String)

Comment: why does this error come? Can you please explain to me

Comment: I have removed the system assertion and tried the code and it was executed perfectly with 100% coverage. But i would like to know why we are getting the error message

Comment: I tried the code and in the result i got System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0A9000000GZBTnEAP; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Cannot delete candidate with a job application: []

Comment: Above code runs and works for me.  You should not be getting an error

Comment: This code is working. Thank you!!!! If we want to assert anything in catch why are we getting an error. The code is fine but when we run the test the test is getting failed